# Transcendental equation $2 x n\cot (2x)= x^2 - n^2$

Tags: trigonometry, closed-form, transcendental-equations

I have a transcendental equation and I have not a mathematical superiour formation (I'm an hydraulic engineer) necessary to solve it.

The equation is : $2 x n\cot (2x)= x^2 - n^2$ or (same equation) :                    $(n\cot (x)-x) (n \tan(x)+x) =0$.

Here $n$ is a constant (I have this $n$, for example $n = 0.5$). 
$x_p = $are the roots of equation above.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you're writing.

Comment: Please edit the formatting of the equation(s) you have because, as written, no one can understand them. If you need help with formatting mathematics, take a look at these two links: [simpler](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [more detailed](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: is `tg` tangent and `ctg` cotangent?

Comment: Very hard to understand.  To start with, what are ctg and tg?  I assume they are transcendental functions but they aren't any of common ones (trig. etc.)?  Or is g(x) a function and c and t are constants/variables?  In that case I don't see how it could be solved without more information about the nature of g(x).

Comment: I think he meant $2xn\cot(2x)= x^2-n^2$. Or $(n\cot(x)-x)(n\tan(x)+x)=0$.

Comment: cot is ctg ( cotangente ) 1/tangente  AND tan is tg is tangente (sin/cos)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer but this kind of transcendental equation are very hard to solve formally and they require very complex method. Anyway this is what I can tell you:

As you said you can rewrite your equation like this:

$$2xn\cot(2x)=x^2-n^2\Rightarrow(n\cot x-x)(n\tan x+x)=0$$

So you have to search from the solution of the two equations:

$$(1)\space\tan x=-\frac xn$$

$$(2)\space\cot x=\frac xn$$

Now taking reciprocals to $(2)$ you get:

$$(2)\space \tan x=\frac nx$$

And in this paper is shown how to solve this two equations: http://www4.ncsu.edu/~ces/pdfversions/52.pdf

Those are closed form solutions and may be not so useful for pratical purpouses so if you need numerical approximation I think that Newton's method is the best (like in the most kinds of situations).